# How can I convert my JavaScript web-application into android application?

Tags: javascript, java, android, web-applications

So, I have developed a Map application which needs to be on android should I need to write code again in android or can in convert the JavaScript web app into android-app anyways to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking for is called 'hybrid mobile app development'.

There are a [number of frameworks](https://mindmajix.com/top-20-hybrid-mobile-app-frameworks) you can use to convert web applications to native ones.
I recommend to go for PhoneGap, as your only requirement is to use JavaScript (the majority of the frameworks are front-end framework bound)

You have to register an Adobe Account and upload zips of your application to build the Android APK when going the PhoneGap group

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1-) You can use Android WebView, and can present your website into your Android App
(best choice)

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

https://www.journaldev.com/9333/android-webview-example-tutorial

2-)You can make it without writing code, there are websites that directly changing websites to the android apk

https://median.co

Comment: In case of webview if i open the app does it opens like a web page?, gonative's charging a bunch!

Comment: Actually, it belongs to you. It will be look like website opened in mobile phones without an address block. You can manually add an address block, disable/enable javascript. Add items, use toolbars out of the webview.